# Why proofs of Cook's Theorem assume k is given (n^k for NTM)?

Tags: np-complete, np-hard, satisfiability

A typical proof of Cook-Levin's Theorem proceeds like this:

> Suppose problem X is in NP. Then there is an NTM M
> deciding X in time n^k, for some k. Given a word w,
> NTM M, **and k**, we construct a Boolean formula φ in polytime(|w|)
> that is satisfiable iff the NTM accepts w, as follows. [...]

Question: why can we assume that k is given?
I agree that "there exists such k",
however knowing that it exists and directly using it in the reduction are different things (to me).
I would expect the reduction to be independent of k (so the formula doesn't depend on k),
but the proof of its correctness relies on the fact that k in N exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the statement of Cook's theorem: it states that for any problem in NP, there exists a reduction from that problem to 3SAT.  The key part is the "there exists".  The proof only needs to show that there exists such a reduction.  For these purposes, it suffices to note that there exists a $k$ such that $M$ runs in time $O(n^k)$.  There is no requirement that we be able to find $k$ or find the reduction.

Comment: Unexpected! Thanks. For the same reason I should have asked why the reduction depends on the NTM M, making the question even more silly, and the answer is the same: "suffice to show `there exists`".

Comment: @Ayrat, for what it's worth, I thought it was a perfectly reasonable question.  The difference between constructive vs non-constructive proofs is tricky, especially in computer science, where our intuition usually goes to constructive arguments.